# Making all values in raster same using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, saga

I need to convert all the values in a raster to one certain value. How can I do this? (I tried using raster calculator, but any operation that would result in a raster having all one value makes it create a raster with no data for whatever reason)

I tired using constant grid, and it also makes rasters with no data

My inputs were:
[image]

The raster I created showed no data:

[image]

To make sure, I looked at the histogram of data values, and it confirms no data (the data should be all 1)
[image]

Comment: Miltiply raster with zero and + value.  R*0+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you have nodata value in your original raster, SAGA **Constant Grid** would come in handy.

From QGIS Processing toolbox, go to `SAGA | Raster Tools`.

On the **Constant grid** window:

- `Name`: Give any name (`value`, `my_raster`, ...)  (*1)
- `Constant Value`: Your aimed value.
- `Data Type`: Select your required data type (*2)
- `Target Grid System`: Select `[1] grid or grid system`
- Ignore `Cellsize`, `Left`, `Right`, `Bottom`, `Top`, and `Fit`
- `Target System [optional]`: Select your **original raster layer**.
- Ignore `Advanced parameters`.

---

(*1) Honestly I do not know why this is needed.

(*2) as of QGIS 2.18.19, it seems SAGA returns Float32 raster regardless which `Data Type` we choose. If you need integer raster (e.g. 0-255), please try `Convert data storage type` to obtain `1-byte integer` following this operation.

---

**Update**

The appearance of output layer (name `Target Grid`) may not look successful, in the Layers panel.

If in doubt, please check the cell values by (1) Load min/max values. or (2) using `Identify Feature` tool.

Comment: It didn't work (I put a picture of the error in the original question)

Comment: @Shane I think you have forgotten your **original raster layer** to put into the `Target System`. That's why your picture (error message) does not show `-TEMPLATE` option.

Comment: I see that now...

Comment: I'm not sure what happened the first time I tried, but the pictures were from a run that was solely to reproduce the error; clearly I'd gotten a bit sloppy by that point

Comment: @Shane your raster with cell value 1 was created successfully.

Comment: What makes you think so? If there's data, shouldn't it show up in the histogram?

Comment: And the raster was black, corresponding to nan in the legend. And also when I closed and reopened the project, QGIS wouldn't load that layer because it said it was bad. If these aren't indications of whether the raster is data value of 1 or no data, then what should I be looking at?

Comment: @Shane You can check the output raster by either (1) Load min/max values. or (2) using `Identify Feature` tool. As to the error while reopening, it happened because QGIS does not automatically save a memory layer. You need to save the produced raster yourself.

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right. It did create the raster correctly

Comment: I think there's a glitch that sometimes makes rasters display as having no data in the legend even though they in fact have data. I'd seen it before but didn't connect the dots to the present "problem"

Comment: @Shane I feel the same way...elusive to say the least.